# Android how to calculate amount of elements on a page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Part of application I'm currently working on act exactly as android shell, shows several pages filled with icons with text labels. User could slide between pages to find needed element. I'm using PagerView with GridView in each page.

Content of each page should fit exactly of visible area, no scroll. The question how to calculate number of icons on each page?

The issue next, I can't call pagerView.getHeight(), I'll have 0 in result because actual layout calculation wasn't executed yet.

UPDATED:

Seems I wasn't able to describe my problem well, I'll try to provide more simple case, suppose I do have activity with status bar at the top and some button bar at the bottom, both fixed height. Whole remaining area in the middle is used by GridView.

Grid view should show rectangular icons, and what I need to calculate is how many icons it could show without scroll (because remaining icons will be shown on next activity).

Comment: do you know the size of each icon?

Comment: yes, this is minor issue, icon size I could get easy

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
public int countElements(ViewGroup group) {

   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
       View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
       Class c = v.getClass();
       if (c == *Icon*) {
          count++;
       }         
    }
    return count;
}
```

In case you have inner views you can check if c is a GroupView and call the method recursively.

Comment: Lior, the problem is, I don't have any child at this point, I DO NEED to calculate how much child icon I can put there. Can you check my update above?

Answer (score 0):

As for your second issue, try using this in onCreate:

```
private void calculateSize(int height, int width){
    int rows = Math.floor(height/imageHeight);
    int columns = Math.floor(width/imageWidth);
    //do something with numbers
}

ViewTreeObserver vto = pagerView.getViewTreeObserver();
if(vto.isAlive()){
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            calculateSize(gridView.getHeight(), gridView.getWidth());
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Justin, same problem as for previous answer, I need to calculate how much icons grid view could contains before processHeigt execution, please see my updated post. Thanks.

Comment: See my edited answer. The observer won't be called until the layout can be measured, then use the width and height to calculate available spaces.